# Running IIS Express in 32-bit crashes my ASP.NET Core web application

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-express, badimageformatexception

I have an ASP.NET Core web application which I'm trying to run in 32-bit with IIS Express. I followed other guides and tips to make IIS run in 32-bit, but every time i try to run the application it crashes with the error message:

> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly. An
>   attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

I have tried the following:

Set the build and debug to run x86
[image: 32bit IIS Express image 1]

[image: 32bit IIS Express image 2]

And unchecked the `Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects`
[image: 32bit IIS Express image 3]

But my project still closes almost immediately with the error mention above. Is there a setting that I am forgetting about or something else I need to do before the project can run in 32-bit.

I'm using visual studio 2017 on Windows 10 with IIS Express version 10.0.14393.0 and AspNetCore 2.1

Comment: What’s the ASP.Core version? 2.1 and 2.2 are different.

Comment: For the error, it is usually caused by the mismatch 32-bit / 64-bit conflict in your project. It seems you have set the main project to 32-bit, have you referenced any 64-bit library? Could you reproduce this issue with a new built-in asp.net core mvc project?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. @Lex My AspNetCore version is 2.1.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. @TaoZhou The only libraries I use are compiled as 32-bit hence why I need the project to run as 32-bit as well. But non of my libraries are loaded on startup, so that shoudn't be the issue

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this in the end? I am having the same issue.

Comment: @AndreiBazanov No unfortunately I never got it to work, so we ended up using the standard .NET for the project instead.

Comment: @Tobiuo - same here. Ah, well. Thanks for coming back to me.